# Terraform destroy -force

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I had installed terraform v1.3.1. When I am trying to force destroy the kubernetes resources using the command `terraform destroy -force`, I get the error shown here. Please help

```
terraform destroy -force
```

> Error: Failed to parse command-line flags
>
> flag provided but not defined: -force
>
> For more help on using this command, run:
> terraform destroy -help

```
terraform -version

Terraform v1.3.1
on linux_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/helm v2.7.0
```

Comment: There is no flag `-force`. Please check tf `-help` for supported flags.

Comment: Actually ... it looks like there used to be a `-force` option in earlier versions of `terraform`; see https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/23552.  Maybe you are using out-of-date instructions or courseware?

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to prevent Terraform for prompting for interactive confirmation of the action, then you have two options.

---

If the goal is to run Terraform in an automation system that doesn't provide an interactive terminal, you can get the same effect of planning and then separately approving the plan by saving the destroy plan to a file and then applying that file:

- `terraform plan -destroy -out=tfplan`
- (review the plan)
- `terraform apply tfplan`

For more details on this, see [Running Terraform in Automation](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/automate-terraform).

---

If you are just toying with Terraform using unimportant temporary infrastructure and you don't care to review and approve the plan at all, you can tell Terraform to skip the interactive confirmation and then immediately apply the change:

- `terraform destroy -auto-approve`

The above is essentially just a shorthand for the following:

- `terraform apply -destroy -auto-approve`

This tells Terraform to create a *destroy plan* and then immediately apply it without any interactive confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete all resources `terraform destroy`. There is no flag for `-force`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `-force` flag for `terrafrom destroy`. You can just run `terrafrom destroy`

If you tried using the flag to skip the interactive confirmation, you can skip the confirmation by running `terraform destroy -auto-approve`